# Sum of first purchase details of all customers

Tags: sql

I have 3 customers in a table. Each one purchased 2 products in 2 months. Now I want to find the purchase amount of each months.

My table looks like this

```
id     purchased amount     month
---------------------------------

1        200                  january

2        300                  january

3        250                  january

1        400                  january

2        600                  january

3        500                  february
```

Now if I enter january then I will get 1  200, 2 300, 3 250

Comment: show your query which you tried..

Comment: And also your desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id,monthname,SUM(amount)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id,monthname
```